# How to find multiple files in a specific folder (iphone cocoa app)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsfilemanager

Lets say i want to check for the presence of file1, file2 and file3 in the folder /User, such that i get to conditionally fire an action if any one of these files are found. How would I go about doing that?

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `fileExistsAtPath` method of [NSFileManager](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for checking the existence of a file at known path.

```
 - (BOOL)fileExistsAtPath:(NSString *)path;
 - (BOOL)fileExistsAtPath:(NSString *)path isDirectory:(BOOL *)isDirectory;
```

Use the method as below ...

```
BOOL file1Exists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:file1Path];
BOOL file2Exists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:file2Path];
BOOL file3Exists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:file3Path];
```

Comment: +1 for explaining the function of fileExistsAtPath, and the seperation of boolean values. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to check file is present in document directory or not.

```
NSString *filePath1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"filePath1.txt"]];
NSString *filePath2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"filePath2.txt"]];
NSString *filePath3 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"filePath3.txt"]];
if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath1] || [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath2] || [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath3]) {
//code.....
}
```

I think this will help you. you can do this for any number of file.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS all the files will be stored in the Document Directory. to search the file in Doc Dir.

```
NSArray *doc=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *docPath = [doc objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *filePath= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/file1",docPath];

NSFileManager *fileManager =[NSFileManager defaulManager];

BOOL result= [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath];
```

By this result you can trigger the action you want to run.